# Applying again to visit UK, long term visit visa

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, bangladeshi-citizens, spanish-residents

I had a UK 6 month visit visa last year which was expired on February 2020.
On my previous application I mentioned that I wanted to visit London but after getting the visa I travelled to Manchester 2 times.
First was for 10 days and second one for 3 days.

Now I want to apply for a long time 2 years visit visa. My friend recently moved to the UK with his Europian passport so on my visit I will meet him but I will pay all my costs I am working and my monthly income is more than 1500£ everything is OK with my bank statement.

I want to know that should my friend have to send me a inviation letter or should I attach it because I will stay at hotel and will visit tourist places together. My plan is to apply on January for going to UK for 6-7 days in February.

My nationality is Bangladeshi and I'm living in Spain as a residence. I have never have been denied any visas. My last visa application was successful. I want to make new appication as my last visa expired.

Comment: Other than visiting a friend, do you have any other reason to convince UKVI that you ‘need’ to visit the UK regularly?

Comment: Due to COVID19, visitors from Spain are currently required to self-isolate for 14 days on arrival in the UK. There's no way to tell when that restriction will be lifted, but it could easily be months. You should check before applying for a visa. There will be no point in visiting the UK just to spend your entire trip in a hotel room.